# Angular paramMap vs queryParamMap?

Tags: angular, routes

What are the different paramMap and queryParamMap?

Angular website says 
paramMap -  An Observable that contains a map of the required and optional parameters specific to the route. The map supports retrieving single and multiple values from the same parameter.

queryParamMap - An Observable that contains a map of the query parameters available to all routes. The map supports retrieving single and multiple values from the query parameter.

I would like to know when I have to use with examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 58, accepted):

ParamMap for routes like `user/:id`. `Id` param belongs only this route.

QueryParamMap is for eg. `user/:id?tab=edit`. `Tab` is a global query param, it can be read from the ActivatedRoute in the user route's component as well as any of its ancestors.

Answer (score 6):

`params`—An Observable that contains the required and optional parameters specific to the route. Use `paramMap` instead.

`queryParams`—An Observable that contains the query parameters available to all routes. Use `queryParamMap` instead.

Comment: Could you elaborate why using one over the other?

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/a/49617621/5697591