# subscribe on route.queryParamMap and route.paramMap causes page loads twice

Tags: angular, angular-routing

As depicted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49617621/492258), I use in my app the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/rooms/lisbon?roomTypes=1
```

And in ngOnInit I subscibes both:

```
this._route.data.subscribe(x => { console.log(1);doCommonBiz(); })

this._route.paramMap.subscribe(param => { console.log(2);doCommonBiz(); })
```

I need to be notified one one of them occured, if any of below routed:

```
http://localhost:8080/rooms/lisbon?roomTypes=2  
http://localhost:8080/rooms/london?roomTypes=1  
http://localhost:8080/rooms/cologne?roomTypes=3
```

But my subscriptions fire twice.

My question is how can I be notified only once by being aware of two subsciption?

Comment: Why did you subscribe both?
I think paramMap give you data what you want

Answer (score -1):

After digging some, I found [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) is what I am looking for.