Disable Div Element in Angular v18 / HTML with Typescript
I am trying to deactivate / activate a div based on the content of my url (query String parameters). If the url does not contain any parameters it should be visible otherwise it should be disabled. Right now it's disabled but switching the boolean does not change anything. I am also getting no error or anything else.
so e.g
the url looks like this: http://localhost:4200/shop it should be visible
the url looks likes this: http://localhost:4200/search/test it should be invisible
Here is my TS
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ShopheaderComponent } from '../shopheader/shopheader.component';
import { Plant } from '../classes/plants';
import { PlantService } from '../services/plant.service';
import { RouterLink, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { NotFoundComponent } from '../not-found/not-found.component';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-shop-landing-page',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ShopheaderComponent, CommonModule, RouterLink, RouterOutlet, NotFoundComponent],
  templateUrl: './shop-landing-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shop-landing-page.component.css']
})
export class ShopLandingPageComponent implements OnInit {
  plants: Plant[] = [];
  hasQueryParam: boolean = true; // Flag for query parameter

  constructor(private plantService: PlantService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Check for query parameter and fetch plants 
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      if (params['searchTerm']) {
        this.plants = this.plantService.getAllPlantsBySearchTerm(params['searchTerm']);
      } else {
        this.plants = this.plantService.getAll();
      }
      // Set hasQueryParam flag based on query parameter presence
      this.hasQueryParam = Object.keys(params).length > 0; 
    });
  }
}

and here is my html div that I would like to disable / enable
<div *ngIf="hasQueryParam" [ngClass]="{'disabled': hasQueryParam}">
    <h4>Shop our bestsellers</h4>
  
    <div class="wrapper"> <ng-container *ngFor="let item of plants">
            <div class="item" *ngIf="item.bestseller">
                <li>
                    <a routerLink="/details/{{item.id}}">
                        <img [src] = "item.imageUrl[0]"/>
                    </a>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="name">
                            {{item.name}} <br>
                            {{item.price | currency}} <br>
                            {{item.rating}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>

Maybe the issue is that "shop" also gets interpreted as a parameter but its only a route
{
        path:"shop", component:ShopLandingPageComponent
    },


There are no query params in your route: "http://localhost:4200/shop". Based on your logic, the hasQueryParam is true when the route is "http://localhost:4200/shop?searchTerm=abc".

But why doesn’t it work?

As mentioned in my previous comment, there is no queryParam in the URL. Have you tried debugging and seeing what value you get in params['searchTerm']? The hasQueryParams is false for both "http://localhost:4200/shop" and "http://localhost:4200/search/test" URLs.

There is a difference between route params and query params. Are you sure you want to read the query params and not the route params? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49615857/angular-parammap-vs-queryparammap

I have a shop page and the div is a slider with items. So when only the shop page is loaded (so "localhost:4200/shop" gets called) I want it to visable but when I for example search for something (so localhost:4200/shop?searchTerm=abc" gets called) in should get disabled.. The only way I see do that is by tracking the content of the query parameters.
